# Test docker clusters locally

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

What are the common practices to test and develop docker containers which will be deployed in clusters in production?

For instance I have three services which will be deployed four times on different machines. In order to test code and other stuff I would like to have a similar environment locally.

How would you achieve that? Docker swarm seems one potential setup but very heavyweight for a development setup, especially if you don't plan to use Docker swarm.

Comment: Use `Vagrant` to create the number of machines you want with the desired OS and settings.

Comment: Swarm cannot de be deployed locally as far as I know. At least not seamlessly, nevertheless once your app is functional and containerized it is ease to deploy it over Swarm (that is just like a Docker daemon)